# How to stop $ionicLoading while executing promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, loading

I have made an `ionicLoading` and I used the same function - `startNow()` to go from `original-page` to `my-next-page`.

For the first time I just call `startNow()` and it goes to directly to `my-next-page` after `$timeout()` service called.

Here's my real problem:

> I have a cancel button on my `myLoadingTemplate.html` and I call the same function `startNow(true)`. The problem is after I click the cancel button during loading, the page was redirect to my `original-page`. However after 2500ms the page still redirect to `my-next-page`.

How to solve this problem?

```
$scope.startNow = function(is_force)
{
     if(is_force===true)
     {
         $state.go('orignal-page');
         $ionicLoading.hide();
     }else
     {
         $ionicLoading.show({
             templateUrl: "myLoadingTemplate.html",
             nBackdrop: false
           }).then(function(){
                   $timeout(function(){ 

                      $state.go('my-next-page');
                      $ionicLoading.hide();

                   },2500);
         });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I get your right, you won't to prevent the delayed state change after the timeout when cancelling. This can be done by actually cancel the timeout. $timeout returns a promise which you can store to cancel it when clicking the cancel button.

Modified your code below, hope this does the trick as you expect it to be :)

Edit: My fault - $ionicLoading.show does not return a promise, the call is incorrect in this case though. Corrected it in the code example below. Also I changed $scope.transitionTimeout to $rootScope.transitionTimeout (HINT: Yes, using the $rootScope isn't very clean, it was the fastest way to illustrate a working example here). The problem is that it's not simply possible to pass a scope to the $ionicLoading service, so when you add a controller to the loading template a new scope will be created in which the transitionTimeout promise isn't defined.

So a clean way to implement this would be to set up a controller for the view and a second for the loading template, and for the communication between both you could use a service holding the promise.

However: A quick and working example is shown below. You can also try it right here: http://play.ionic.io/app/4349c868f8b4

```
$scope.startNow = function(is_force)
{
     if(is_force===true)
     {
         // cancel your timeout by using the reference
         // HINT: $rootScope implementation is not the cleanest solution here
         //       should mainly illustrate a quick solution! E.g. a better solution
         //       would be to implement a LoadingService, which stores such a
         //       transition timeout promise uniquely
         $timeout.cancel($rootScope.transitionTimeout);

         $state.go('orignal-page');
         $ionicLoading.hide();
     }else
     {
         $ionicLoading.show({
           templateUrl: "myLoadingTemplate.html",
           nBackdrop: false
         })

         // store the promise here
         $rootScope.transitionTimeout = $timeout(function(){ 
           $state.go('my-next-page');
           $ionicLoading.hide();
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer, sorry, missed the two points - check the edit and the working example in the link and let me know if you got it working. :)

Comment: Could you specify your problem though? Don't see any additional possibility than providing code in addition to a link to a working example you can test in your browser. The solution is valid though, as the link proves. So if you need advice regarding your code I'd need code snippets. Just would like to add: Generally it's simply rude to only repeat this phrase without appreciating the work done so far at all, doesn't really raise the motivation of volunteers doing there best to support you...

Comment: Do not be sad..I accept your answer since you fill the requirement. Thanks   for your hard work to help me.. have a nice day.. cheers